# How many simultaneous terminal pseudo connections can support my linux server?

Tags: debian, ssh, terminal, telnet

My debian distribution has 62 virtual text terminal in `/dev/tty`.

- Does this mean that my server can support up to simultaneous 62 ssh or telnet connections?
- For each connection I note that it created a new file in `/dev/pts`. What is the relationship between `/dev/tty` and `/dev/pts`?